# js - can i convert a number with % in number?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Is it possible convert a number with % value (string) in a number?
I'm working with amCharts v3 and i use this function for set the value (inner and innerRadius)

```
"radius": ( 5 + ( Math.floor( index / 2 ) * ( 100 / length ) ) ),
```

After i have to put a "%" to make the chart scalable based on the size of the container like tgis

But after i have this error

> Error:  attribute d: Expected number, “ M397,NaN L397,0 A0,0,…”

Also innerRadius and radius accept String/Number (from reference), i don't understand why because also with other mathematical expression i don't have error putting "%" at the end of the value. Is it possible convert a number with "%" at the end in a number?

Comment: `parseInt('123%')`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: How i have to use it? from console: parseInt is not a function

Comment: I showed an example call, I linked to the documentation … what more do you need?

Comment: parseInt remove the "%", i need to mantain the "%"

Comment: Well then you will have to append the % to the value again _after_ you did your calculation.

Comment: i'm already doing this.

Comment: Okay, enough of this dropping small pieces of info one after the other in comments … Please go read [ask], and then edit your question to include a proper description of the problem. With just that one line you have shown, it is close to impossible to tell what you actually need.

Comment: There's an `NaN` in the error message. That's a big enough hint that something is wrong in your formula and/or values. Like the previous commenter said, edit your question, preferably with a embedded demo with your code and values that are being set in that line that are causing this to break.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you parse the number to int and then divide by one hundred?

```js
"radius": ( 5 + ( Math.floor( parseInt(index)/100 / 2 ) * ( 100 / length ) ) ),
```

This should give you the result you are looking for.

But if `radius` is just for the ui append the `%` yourself otherwise it's fine for calculation.

```js
"radius": `${( 5 + ( Math.floor( parseInt(index)/100 / 2 ) * ( 100 / length ) ) )} %`,
```